# What constructor I am missing? I really dont get it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, constructor, state

I am getting this error while loading this page.

I am not even using the constructor approach.

```
TypeError: Illegal constructor
renderWithHooks
C:/Users/sfsf/Desktop/ServerGuy/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16260
  16257 |   }
  16258 | }
  16259 | 
> 16260 | var children = Component(props, refOrContext);
        | ^  16261 | 
  16262 | if (didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdate) {
  16263 |   do {
View compiled
```

I am trying to implement the simple react code. All the other pages are working but since I am getting this code continuously. I am using nodejs and mongodb.

I want to load the Component on click defined in the Route.js file.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';
import { getUser, getToken, logout } from './helpers';

const History = () => {
  var un = getUser();

var [posts2, setPosts2] = useState([]);

    const fetchPosts2 = () => {

        axios
            .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/history/${un}`,
            )
            .then(response => {
                setPosts(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => alert(error));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts2();
    }, []);

    return (
          <div>
            <div className="content">
            <div className="data pl-sm">

              {posts2.map((item, index) => (

                // if(index < 1){
                //      return(
                //        <div className="container">
                //           <h1 className="display-4">You do not have any search history yet.</h1>
                //        </div>
                //  );
                // }
                //    else{
                    // return(
                       <div className="container">
                          <h1 className="display-4">Search History</h1>
                      <table className="table">
                      <thead>
                      <th>
                         S No.
                       </th>
                      <th>
                         Search Word
                       </th>
                              <th>
                         Time
                       </th>
                       </thead>
                     <tbody>
                     <tr>
                            <td>{index} </td>
                           </tr>
                          <tr>
                      <td>{item.word} </td>
                           </tr>
                                  <tr>
                            <td>{item.time} </td>
                           </tr>
                     </tbody>
                       </table>

                       </div>
                    // );
                //   }
              )
              )}

            </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        );
};

export default History;
```

Comment: `I want to load the Component on click defined in the Route.js file.` Where are you doing that in the code?

Comment: I tried your code but I haven't seen such error https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-dijkstra-jijzi?file=/src/App.js.